# load silverlight controls in asp.net page

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight project which contains 2 silverlight controls Control_1 and Control_2. Please note that its in same app.Now I have asp.net project which will use any of these silverlight control (either Control_1 or Control_2).

Challenge is how do I tell silverlight which control to load. I used param property in html object to pass the parameters and tell the app which control to load at runtime?

But what if there are more than 2 controls in same project? We cannot have a long switch case statement in the app file only to load the controls. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There isn't, and this is not about Silverlight itself, this is normal logic.

In your App.xaml file, put this:

```
using System.Windows; // Application, StartupEventArgs

namespace SilverlightApplication
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify the main application UI
            if(SomeCondition == true)
                this.RootVisual = new Control1();
            else
                this.RootVisual = new Control2();

            // In the same way, you may define a switch statment
        }
    }
}
```

You may decide what that condition is by passing parameters to the XAP file, and finally you access those by accessing `e.InitParams` in `Application_Startup`

For more info: [Application.RootVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.rootvisual%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this switch case, Is this the only way to implement??

Comment: I can't think of ways to avoid this switch case (and a little bit lost about what do you want to achieve). Since this class `App` which inherits from `Application` is the only entry point, yes, I think this is the only way.