# large silverlight site (hundreds of pages)

Tags: silverlight, web

When you surf a silverlight site, I believe it downloads the site to the client.

Excluding practicality, lets say your going to develop a large full silverlight site with nearly a thousand pages of static content.

Is there any way you can set the compiler to divide the silverlight app in small parts that will only download as a user attempts to access different areas of the huge site?

Comment: In practice of course you are not likely to have thousands of pages of unique Xaml.  You my have thousands of entities that are of a much smaller range of types and you will only need a similarly small number of Xaml templates to render those entities.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) of Silverlight.
With it you can create small silverlight projects and load them when you need.
Here are some links:

[3 Steps to MEF - Export, Import, Compose](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-Episode-4-3-Steps-to-MEF-Export-Import-Compose) from silverlight.tv
[When and Where to use MEF](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-7-When-and-Where-to-use-MEF) from silverlight.tv
[Using MEF with Silverlight 4 for Extensibility](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/using-mef-silverlight-4-extensibility/) from silverlight.net

Comment: +1 A good answer to the theoretical situation described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific it downloads the XAP file to the client, which is the end product for your silverlight project.

(Input) Silverlight project -> (Output) one XAP File (containing the main assembly and its dependencies) compressed in a normal ZIP file, but ironically renamed to take XAP extension.

Yes, this is doable, see my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860154/load-silverlight-controls-in-asp-net-page/4860342#4860342), you need the same methodology depending on the control (portion) you need upon a specified condition.